# Unsatisfied dependency exception for bean type java.util.Properties

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a `Spring Framework` `5.3.10` application — not `Spring Boot`. I'm running into a rather trivial problem creating/injecting a `Properties` bean. Here is my setup:

```java
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class PersistenceConfig {
  @Bean
  public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate() throws NamingException {
    return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource());
  }

  ...

  @Bean("employeeQueries")
  public Properties employeeQueries() throws IOException {
    final var properties = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    properties.setLocation(new FileSystemResource("database/employee-queries.properties"));
    return properties.getObject();
  }
}
```

```java
@Repository
@Transactional
@AllArgsConstructor
public class EmployeeJdbc implements IEmployeeJdbc {
  private final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template;

  @Qualifier("employeeQueries")
  private final Properties queries; // Not getting injected >:/

  ...
```

The stacktrace is pretty clear on the issue, but I'm still unable to make it work:

```sh
2021-12-19 19:19:40,771 |- ERROR in o.s.t.context.TestContextManager:252 [main] - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@14e2e1c3] to prepare test instance [org.acme.persistence.EmployeeJdbcTest@2b4786dd]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
  at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
  at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
  at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
  at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
  at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
  at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$8(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
  at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:368)
  at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$9(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
  at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
  at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:362)
  at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:283)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
  at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:282)
  at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:272)
  at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
  at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:271)
  at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
  at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:102)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
  at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101)
  at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
  at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
  at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
  at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
  at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
  at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
  at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
  at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
  at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
  at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
  at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
  at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
  at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
  at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
  at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
  at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeJdbc' defined in file [/home/gorre/Workshop/Development/java-spring-jdbc/target/classes/org/acme/persistence/EmployeeJdbc.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.Properties' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="employeeQueries")}
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
  at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:127)
  at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
  at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:275)
  at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:243)
  at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
  at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
  ... 69 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.Properties' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="employeeQueries")}
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1790)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1385)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
  ... 87 common frames omitted
```

Any clues on why Spring is unable to discover that bean? `namedParameterJdbcTemplate` is on the same file and the setup without `employeeQueries` works fine — I'm just trying to place the SQL queries inside `.properties` files, instead on the Java source code.

Lombok's configuration already has `lombok.copyableannotations += org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier`.

Currently, I only have one bean of type `Properties`. Regardless, I'm assigning it a fixed identifier, because I'll have more in the future. The "offending" bean is actually getting instantiated correctly (or at least that's what I see when I put a debug point in the IDE):

[image]

Comment: Just to be sure: both classes (the `@Configuration` and the `@Repository`) use `java.util.Properties`?

Comment: `PersistenceConfig` declares the bean (`employeeQueries` of type `java.util.Properties`), and `EmployeeJdbc` makes use of it.

Comment: Can you set a debug point or a log statement in the producer method to check whether the producer method is triggered at all?

Comment: Have you tried to make it run without Lombok just to rule out Lombok related issues?

Comment: I did try also without Lombok; that's why I discovered: `lombok.copyableannotations`, but no, it didn't work either. All I can think of is somehow the setup for the unit/integration tests is not correct, but like I said, everything works flawlessly, except now that I'm trying to integrate the `Properties` bean for externalizing the SQL queries.

Comment: Does this mean it worked without lombok?

Comment: [`afterPropertiesSet`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertiesFactoryBean.html#afterPropertiesSet--)!? ..alternatively: expose the factory rather than the properties...

Comment: OK, that's quite unfortunate to my eyes :/ ...any reason why this needs to programmatically call `properties.afterPropertiesSet()` to work? I would really like to avoid that. It actually works fine after adding that call, so you are on the money on this one! Thanks!

Comment: spring ...no boot! its all "magic", but more manual! xDxDxD

Comment: it is the "pattern" of "intializationBean", before `afterProeprtiesSet` (e.g) `location` has *no effect*..

Comment: OK, I'll live in peace with that call :) ...looks like I'm quite used to Spring Boot these days, and I'm losing sight of everything that happens behind scenes with time and just using what's provided by default. If you provide your solution as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: a good detailed answer is always  "hard work", but i tried little! Thx &welcome

Comment: Another option would probably be not to use `PropertiesFacforyBean` to create a `Properties` instance but `Properties.load(InputStream)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The used (spring standard) "factory" implements `FactoryBean<Properties>` as `InitializingBean` ...

#### As designed Approach

```
@Bean
public FactoryBean<Properties> employeeQueries() throws IOException {
    final var factory = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    // please prefer: File- ressource with *absolute* path, alternatively (spring) Classpath- or ServletContext-
    factory.setLocation(new FileSystemResource("database/employee-queries.properties"));
    return factory;
}
```

#### Straight (problem solution/low impact) Approach:

We need to:

```
factory.afterProertiesSet();
```

To:

> ... perform validation of its (factory's) overall configuration and final initialization when all (factory)bean properties have been set.

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertiesFactoryBean.html#afterPropertiesSet--

Before we can:

```
factory.getObject();
```

But the said only applies within the `@Bean` (configuration) method body, because as soon leaving it, Spring would "jump in" (again & `afterPropertiesSet`/validate "under the hood", e.g. when we would expose the factory instead of the properties).

For more details:

- [FactoryBean#getObject](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertiesFactoryBean.html#getObject--)
- [InitializingBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html)
- [BeanFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html)

---

And as "rule of thumb":

*Always*, when we (initialize):

```
(any spring)InitializingBean factory = new InitializingBean();
factory.setXXX(...)
factory.setYYY(...)
```

We *should* (validate):

```
factory.afterProertiesSet();
```

*Before* we can:

```
factory.getObject();
```

Comment: I just tried with `PropertiesFactoryBean` as return type instead of `Properties`, and it works exactly the same. An alternative answer could be: just use `PropertiesFactoryBean` instead, and `afterPropertiesSet` doesn't need to be called programmatically. Like you pointed out, the documentation is clear on this.

Comment: one little problem (more) i noticed: you use relative path on FileResource ... is that only for the post/simplicity? otherwise: it has some "flaws"! (Dev/Test/CI-CD/Container/Cloud...)

Comment: ..and updated the answer with the "as designed" approach...is the `@Qualifier` still correct/used ..and Repository unchanged!??

Comment: "database/employee-queries.properties", sounds better with: `ClasspathResource("/database/employee-queries.properties")` !;)

Comment: I actually ended up using `ClasspathResource` for it.